# Why can't I simplify my expression?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to simplify some expressions containing square roots, yet it seems that Mathematica has trouble dealing with them. For instance, consider the following:

```
Simplify[(1 + Sqrt[1 + z]) (-3 + Sqrt[5 + 4 Sqrt[1 + z] + z]) - z, Assumptions -> z > 0]
```

I do know that this is equal to 0, but `Simplify` is unable to figure this out. (Using Series still allows me to verify this). Since all rooted values are positive, there should be no issues because of sign.

I have a bunch of other functions similarly shaped, which certainly contain significant simplifications, but for which I don't know how to figure out the result (and for which `Series` is no help).

Any advice?

Comment: Reduce sees it is zero. `expr=(1+Sqrt[1+z]) (-3+Sqrt[5+4 Sqrt[1+z]+z])-z;Reduce[expr==0,z,Reals]` gives `z >= -1` but using this, `FullSimplify` can't simplify it to zero. May be it needs more special tricks for `FullSimplify` to do it. Otherwise, use `Reduce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### FullSimplify seems to yield $0$ even without the assumption if the problem is reformulated

I think the problem is related to the assumed branchcut of square root function. I defined your expression as follows

```
givenExpression[z_] := (1 + Sqrt[1 + z]) (-3 + Sqrt[5 + 4 Sqrt[1 + z] + z]) - z;
```

which does not simplify any more as claimed:

```
FullSimplify[givenExpression[z]]
```

> -z + (1 + Sqrt[1 + z]) (-3 + Sqrt[5 + z + 4 Sqrt[1 + z]])

However, if I change my variable $z$ to $z-1$, I immediately get $0$:

```
FullSimplify[givenExpression[z - 1]]
```

> 0

### Possible issue with branchcut

It is actually easy to see the issue with branch cut. We see that

```
givenExpression[z - 1]
```

> $-z+\left(\sqrt{z}+1\right) \left(\sqrt{z+4 \sqrt{z}+4}-3\right)+1$

and we see that **FullSimplify** assume

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[4 + 4 Sqrt[z] + z] == 2 + Sqrt[z]]
```

> True

However this is actually not so trivial. Indeed **Reduce** gives a warning  and refuses to evaluate for the same expression:

```
Reduce[Sqrt[4 + 4 Sqrt[z] + z] == 2 + Sqrt[z]]
```

> Reduce::useq: The answer found by Reduce contains unsolved equation(s) {0==2+Sqrt[z]-Sqrt[4+4 Power[<<2>>]+z]}. A likely reason for this is that the solution set depends on branch cuts of Wolfram Language functions.

which returns back

> 0 == 2 + Sqrt[z] - Sqrt[4 + 4 Sqrt[z] + z]

Comment: `Reduce` just needs the assumption `Assuming[z >= 0, Reduce[Sqrt[4 + 4 Sqrt[z] + z] == 2 + Sqrt[z]]]` evaluates to `True`

Comment: What I am showing above is that the equation is generically true even without the assumption: **FullSimplify** confirms it. However, this is probably a subtle result as **Reduce** refuses the confirm it due to branch cut issues, which can be avoided if the value of $z$ is restricted as you suggest. However, as I showed in the last part, even this result is only generically true as there seems to be $z>0$ values for which the result does not hold.

Comment: If you use inexact numbers you should expect inexact results. If you `Rationalize` the random numbers the exact results are zero. `Module[{numbers}, numbers = Rationalize[RandomReal[{0, 100}, 10], 0];
 Grid[FullSimplify[Transpose@{numbers, givenExpression /@ numbers}]]]`

Comment: @Soner, look at my answer. The expression is zero for all (even complex) z.

Comment: @Akku14 I show in the first part of my answer that **FullSimplify** yields zero for the expression  *without any assumptions* if we reparametrize the questions. This means the result is already generically zero for any object, including but not limited to complex numbers.

Comment: @Bob Ah thanks, my bad. Correcting it now.

Comment: @Soner, I refered to your sentence " However, as I showed in the last part, even this result is only generically true as there seems to be z>0 values for which the result does not hold.", which contradicts your other result and my result and is only an effect of  low precision.

Comment: @Akku14 The last part of my result was actually not contradicting my other results or yours as **Simplify** or **FullSimplify** only considers generic cases whereas isolated contradictions may exist. However as Bob pointed out it was my bad, forgetting to include **Rationalize**. I omitted that part now that it is irrelevant (and incorrect).

Answer (score 2):

Help `Reduce` writing the z as `z = r*Exp[I*phi]` , and it easily prooves the givenexpression to be zero.

For negative real z:

```
Simplify[Reduce[givenExpression[r E^(I Pi)] == 0 && r >= 0, r], 
         r >= 0]

(*   True   *)
```

For positive real  z:

```
Simplify[Reduce[givenExpression[r E^(I 0)] == 0 && r >= 0, r], r >= 0]

(*   True   *)
```

And it also works for all complex numbers

```
Simplify[Reduce[givenExpression[r E^(I phi)] == 0 && r >= 0], 
         r >= 0 && phi \[Element] Reals]

(*   True   *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or Simply

```
Simplify[(1 + Sqrt[1 + z]) (-3 + Sqrt[5 + 4 Sqrt[1 + z] + z]) - z /. 
  z -> u - 1]
(* 0 *)
```